# Take each class value and append it to <select>

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I want to take each value of .option and append it to the  tag like an option.
I've tried this:

```
$( ".option" ).each(function() {
    var add = $( ".option" ).text();        
    $('<option value="' + add.toLowerCase() + '">' + add + '</option>' ).appendTo( $( "#select" ) );;
});
```

HTML

```
<select id="select">

</select>

<div class="option">Lamp</div>
<div class="option">Lamp2</div>
<div class="option">Lamp3</div>
```

But it's not working properly, it appends them as options in the select tag but it also places each value one after another.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/3vvy1yev/2/)

Comment: Side note: instead of `$('<option value="' + add.toLowerCase() + '">' + add + '</option>' )`, you'd be safer using functions to add attributes and HTML, instead of a bunch of string manipulation: `$('<option></option>').val(add.toLowerCase()).html(add)`

Comment: @Joeenos it's the first thing i did but since I was re-pulling the .option, it didn't work and I ended up "desfigurating" it like so of frustration...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in an `.each` but reselect your options inside it. Just use the `this` keyword :

```
$( ".option" ).each(function(){

    var add = $( this ).text();

    $('<option value="' + add.toLowerCase() + '">' + add + '</option>' ).appendTo( $( "#select" ) );

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vvy1yev/3/)

Comment: Damn...I just can't believe it...I feel so stupid now, +1 and accepted :) Thanks

Comment: @Alin programmation, always the small things that f*ck us

Comment: Yup, I'm calling it a night :) Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 2):

You're re-pulling `.option` each time. Since you're in the loop, you only care about the current one:

```
var add = $(this).text();
```

Comment: Well...Like i said, I feel so stupid now...I guess I'll call it a night... +1

Answer (score 2):

Dunno if someone interesting but I create the same result using a recursive function:

```js
(function add(obj, i) {
  console.log(i);
  if (i < obj.length) {
    var txt1 = $(obj).eq(i).text()
    $("<option>" + txt1 + "</option>").appendTo("select");
    i++;
    return add(obj, i);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}($(".option"), 0));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select"></select>
<div class="option">Lamp</div>
<div class="option">Lamp2</div>
<div class="option">Lamp3</div>
```

Comment: Well, this sure works and it might come in handy, who knows, Thanks. +1